# Linux Ubuntu server running in VMWare: Make url public and also open a certain port?

Tags: server, apache2, vmware

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu Server in VMWare. My ultimate goal is to run a service which will use websockets to communicate with an Android app.

I installed Apache (which I don't even know if I need), and my IP is `192.168.137.130`. However I can only see the site from my local computer. Other computers can't open that IP.

How can I make that computer visible on the internet?

Comment: 192.168.x.x IP addresses are local LAN addresses, and are not visible to the internet.

Comment: @AntonChanning OK, so what is the solution to my problem ?

Comment: That is a lot more complex...

Comment: ...by which I mean you're attempting something I've never tried and so can't help with. ;-)

Comment: I can help you with this, but only to the point of getting that computer open to the internet. Your question has too many questions in it, which makes it really hard for any one person to answer. Choose one question to start with and edit everything else out. Do some research about the others on this site to make sure you don't have a duplicate question, and then make a new question if you're still confused.

Comment: @Zacharee1 my question is how to make my ubuntu server which is running from vmware, public to the internet through an IP. i dont see why this is that hard to answer. I am just describing my usecase

Comment: @Shiro but you also ask how to make that port interact with a websocket running from Android, using C++ code. That's a lot of questions in one. Take that out and tell me the model of your home router and I can write up an answer.

Comment: @Zacharee1 All I am asking is if I would need to open that port or grant some sort of extra access. I am not asking you to write code for me.  router: ZXHN H168N

Comment: I wouldn't know. The only thing I can instruct on is how to make your computer accessible from the web. Please ask the other thing in a new question.

Comment: @Shiro I need the model of your router. If you don't have port forwarding, it's not possible.

Comment: I also need to leave soon, but I will still answer this if no one else has.

Comment: @Shiro sorry, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find very much documentation on your router (ZTE ZXHN H168N), but from what I can see, it should have the necessary features to make your computer visible from the web.

The main feature you need is port forwarding, which allows you to open up certain ports used on local IPs to connections from the internet. For instance, the default HTTP port is 80. This is what you want to use if you plan on having some sort of web interface.

To set up port forwarding, go to your router's web config interface (most likely `192.168.137.1`). Log into it and find the page where you can set up port forwarding. Like I said before, I can't find very much about that router, so I'm not exactly sure where this is, but it shouldn't be too difficult to find.

Once you are on the port forwarding configuration page, you can now set up the port forward. In the IP Address field, put the IP of the computer you plan to use as the server. For the port, use whatever port you want. I will use 80 as an example. If you so need, you can also set up other ports to point to the same IP address. This will probably come in handy for your ultimate goal.

Now that you have your router set to forward incoming connections on port 80 to your server, you will need to find your external IP address. To do this, Google **"what's my IP"** and it should be the first thing to show up. Now, test that port forwarding works by entering this IP address into the address bar of your browser. Since you have Apache installed, you should see a test page. If not, verify Apache is running and that you set the port forward up correctly.

Since most external IP addresses are dynamic, meaning they change every so often, I recommend setting up a service that will give you a sub-domain that will always point to your public IP, even when it changes. The service I use is called [No-IP](http://noip.com). It requires the installation of a program on some computer on your local network (preferably one that is always on), which it uses to find your current IP address at all times. Visit the site for more information on how to set up dyanamic DNS.